# how to make a regex to accept ONLY alphabet and space

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

i am using this regex but it still doesn't accept a 'whitespace' input. though it restricts any 'special character'..

.replace(/[0-9]|\W|^\s/,'')

Any help is much appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `/[a-zA-Z\s]/`. The `\s` covers spaces (tabs, newlines, etc.). If you literally just want a space " " then change it to `/[a-zA-Z ]/`.

Comment: will it work in .replace function?

Comment: Of course. :) `string.replace(/[a-zA-Z ]/g, "")` will remove all of the letters and spaces and `string.replace(/[^a-zA-Z ]/g, "")` will remove anything that isn't a letter or a space. :)